# NeoVim does not pick up ruby defined by rbenv/asdf

Tags: neovim

On my clean install macOS Big Sur (with migrated user account), I am having the mentioned problem in (homebrew) NeoVim 0.4 with Neovim gem (0.8.1) using zsh.

```
:ruby puts RUBY_VERSION
2.7.2

:echo system('ruby -v')
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]

:check health provider
- INFO: Ruby: ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
```

I get the same output with `-u NONE`, `-u NORC`, `--no-plugin`.

I tested with clean `.zshrc` and `.bashprofile` and still getting the same problem in this account.

I have tried with PATH env minimally set (working asdf/rbenv) and still getting the same problem.

However, I cannot reproduce this on another account on the same machine.

Where should I look into next to fix the problem in my account?

This is related to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088726/neovim-does-not-use-ruby-specified-by-rbenv-on-macos)

Comment: On my 2 other Linux machines, the problem does not exist. The other (clean) account on the same macOS also does not has the problem. So I think Neovim can use other rubies.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Neovim interface to all external programs is built on top of msgpack-rpc (`:h remote-plugin` for plugin specific stuff). So it's very different from Vim.

Comment: @Matt I guess I should read remote-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. I have this (duplicated code) in my `~/.zprofile` (which also present in the `/etc/zprofile`)

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

I think I had somehow added in there. Now **I remove and it is working fine now**.

UPDATE:

The reason I removed from `~/.zprofile` is

- the other (newly created) clean account is working fine without its `$USER/.zprofile`.
- according to [this source](https://medium.com/@rajsek/zsh-bash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc-e30045652f2e), the `path_helper` script will run for **Interactive login** shell (but ***not*** *Interactive non-login* & *Script*).

Comment: I would recommend not removing this (though mine is in `~/.zshenv`)—it's a helpful "base path" configuration step. Better would be to make sure that any overrides to path are put at the front so that they take precedence? E.g., homebrew-installed programs are earlier on my path than system programs, and other stuff is later.

Comment: It is also present in the `/etc/zprofile`. (I don't know Big Sur put it in there or it is already there before).